# Can we create n no.of NSMutableArray dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm getting the n value from the user, according to it I want to create n number of `NSMutableArray` .

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, just add the arrays to another `NSMutableArray`. Use this code:

```
NSMutableArray *outerArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [outerArray addObject:innerArray];
}
```

Comment: I would probably make a small adjustment to this, and change the creation of the first array to use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:n]` for a slight optimization.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n= 5; // or whatever user gives you
count = 0;
NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray array];

while(count < n)
{
   NSMutableArray *anArray = [NSMutableArray array];
   [arrayOfArrays addObject: anArray];
   count ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using an array of arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *arrays = [NSMutableArray new];

while (gotMoreInput) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    [array addObject:@"Some data"];
    [arrays addObject:array];
}
```